# What's the safest way to store data on a server abroad?

Tags: storage, confidentiality, cloud-storage

A very good friend of mine is a journalist in a country where the state is becoming more and more despotic. 
She would like to store critical data on a server abroad. Is there any service that would be safe for her ?

Comment: encrypt it.Save it in google drive

Comment: We cannot comment on any particular service, but we can talk about techniques.

Comment: @VipulNair Just dumping it on Google Drive may be okay in this specific instance, but for e.g. a business trying to store data redundantly it may be a legal problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She can encrypt her files locally on the computer that she is working on (using a tool such as pgp), then store the encrypted files on any server.